# Limit involving the fractional part and the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Helo,

Let $F(n)$ be the $n$th Fibonacci number, if $\left\{ x\right\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, how proving

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left\{ \frac{F(2n)}{F(k)}\right\} =1-\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

A lecturer wrote this formula on the board without reference and without proof! Thank you for any hint.

ps: the proposed limit is wrong. See the answer below which proves that the limit does indeed exist but has value $3\log(2)/4$.

Comment: This might be better suited for math.SE; I haven't gone all the way through it but it seems as though it should be fairly straightforward using the usual Fibonacci identities to simplify the fractional-part term and turn it into a Riemann integral limit.

Comment: I thought about it but I can't get much done with Binet's formula. It seems to me that something more subtle is needed. The speaker had cited this example in relation to the problem of Dirichlet divisors so I thought of mathoverflow rather than MSE.

Comment: I know that we have $\left\{ x\right\} =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{j\geq1}\frac{\sin\left(2\pi jx\right)}{j}$ but I can't see the equidistribution theorem you are mentioning.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the lecturer?

Comment: I just asked but as it is a consequence of more general work he does not want to communicate certain results. On the other hand, he finds it normal that people have fun searching. The theme was the Dirichlet divisor problem formulated as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{n}{k}\right\} =\left(1-\gamma\right)n+O\left(n^{\theta+\varepsilon}\right)
$$

and for which increasing functions $f$ do we also have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{f(n)}{f(k)}\right\} =C_{f}n+O\left(n^{\theta+\varepsilon}\right)
$$      and $f(n)=F(n)$ doesn't work since there are two limits for $C_f$.

Comment: I don't understand the downotes. This is a rather tricky limit, and it has a different value than stated in the original post. See my response below.

Comment: More precisely, I don't understand the "close" votes. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The statement is not correct. The correct statement is:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left\{ \frac{F(2n)}{F(k)}\right\}=\frac{3\log 2}{4}.$$
That is, the limit is $\approx 0.519860385$ instead of $\approx 0.518788175$. As a numerical verification, for $n=10^6$, the average under the limit  is $\approx 0.519853615$ (according to  SAGE).

More generally, we shall prove the following.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{8}n+O(\sqrt{n}),&\text{$n$ is odd};\\
\frac{3\log 2}{4}n+O(\sqrt{n}),&\text{$n$ is even}.
\end{cases}$$
The idea of the proof is that the fractional part of $F(n)/F(k)$ is typically very close to $0$ or $1$, and the two cases follow a simple pattern.
We can restrict to $k\nmid n$ in the sum, because otherwise the fractional part is zero. Accordingly, we shall consider
$$n=2mk\pm r\qquad\text{with}\qquad r\in\{1,2,\dotsc,k-1\}.$$

If $L(v)$ denotes the $v$-th Lucas number, then we have the identity
$$F(u)L(v)=\begin{cases}
F(u+v)+(-1)^v F(u-v),&u\geq v;\\
F(u+v)-(-1)^u F(v-u),&u\leq v.
\end{cases}$$
Plugging $(mk,mk\pm r)$ for $(u,v)$, we obtain the following congruences:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
F(2mk+r)&\equiv F(r)(-1)^{mk}&&\pmod{F(mk)},\\
F(2mk-r)&\equiv F(r)(-1)^{mk-r-1}&&\pmod{F(mk)}.
\end{alignat*}
These congruences are also valid modulo $F(k)$, because $F(k)$ divides $F(mk)$. We infer that:
$$\{F(n)/F(k)\}=
\begin{cases}
F(r)/F(k),&n=2mk+r,\quad mk\equiv 0\pmod{2};\\
1-F(r)/F(k),&n=2mk+r,\quad mk\not\equiv 0\pmod{2};\\
1-F(r)/F(k),&n=2mk-r,\quad mk\equiv n\pmod{2};\\
F(r)/F(k),&n=2mk-r,\quad mk\not\equiv n\pmod{2}.\\
\end{cases}$$
It is now convenient to introduce the notation
$$I(n,t):=\mathbb{N}\cap\left(\frac{n}{t+1},\frac{n}{t}\right),$$
because then the cases $n=2mk+r$ correspond to $k\in I(n,2m)$, while the cases $n=2mk-r$ correspond to $k\in I(n,2m-1)$. Then we see that:

- for odd $m$ the contribution of $k\in I(n,2m)$ is $\frac{1}{2}|I(n,2m)|+O(1)$;
- for odd $m$ the contribution of $k\in I(n,2m-1)$ is $\frac{1}{2}|I(n,2m-1)|+O(1)$;
- for even $m$ the contribution of $k\in I(n,2m)$ is $O(1)$;
- for even $m$ and odd $n$ the contribution of $k\in I(n,2m-1)$ is
  $O(1)$;
- for even $m$ and even $n$ the contribution of $k\in I(n,2m-1)$ is
  $|I(n,2m-1)|+O(1)$.

Now we choose a positive integer $M$, and sum up the contributions of $I(n,2m)$ and $I(n,2m-1)$ for $m\in\{1,2,\dotsc,M\}$. This way we see that
$$\sum_{k=\lceil n/(2M+1)\rceil}^{n}\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}=\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{k\in I(n,2m)}\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}
+\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{k\in I(n,2m-1)}\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}.\tag{$\ast$}$$
If $n$ is odd, then up to an error of $O(M)$, the right-hand side of $(\ast)$ equals
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{1\leq m\leq M\\\text{$m$ odd}}}\left(\frac{n}{2m-1}-\frac{n}{2m+1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{8}n+O\left(\frac{n}{M}\right).$$
The contribution of $k<n/(2M+1)$ is $O(n/M)$, hence in fact
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}=\frac{\pi}{8}n+O\left(M+\frac{n}{M}\right).$$
If $n$ is even, then up to an error of $O(M)$, the right-hand side of $(\ast)$ equals
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{1\leq m\leq M\\\text{$m$ odd}}}\left(\frac{n}{2m-1}-\frac{n}{2m+1}\right)+\sum_{\substack{1\leq m\leq M\\\text{$m$ even}}}\left(\frac{n}{2m-1}-\frac{n}{2m}\right)=\frac{3\log 2}{4}n+O\left(\frac{n}{M}\right).$$
The contribution of $k<n/(2M+1)$ is $O(n/M)$, hence in fact
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{F(n)}{F(k)}\right\}=\frac{3\log 2}{4}n+O\left(M+\frac{n}{M}\right).$$
In both cases we choose $M=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$, and we obtain the claimed asymptotic formula with error term $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this proof which turns out to be quite technical. I suppose the other limit is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\left\{ \frac{F(2n+1)}{F(k)}\right\} =2\log2-1$$ Do you think your $M$ can be $O(n^{1/2})$?

Comment: @Babar It is not clear why you say "the other limit" as there is only one limit in your post. Of course there is an other limit in your recent comment, but by saying "the other limit" you seem to refer to earlier discussions (where this "other limit" was not present). I guess it is a language problem. Regarding $M$, it is only a technical quantity introduced in the proof (it is not present in the final result). Since the $k$-sum over each $I(r,n)$ converges rapidly, one can take $M$ to be a quantity growing with $n$ slowly, but why would you do that? I have not checked if $M=n^{1/2}$ is OK.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. If $f(x)=F(x)$ the Fibonacci numbers then we have two limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\{ \frac{f(n)}{f(k)}\right\} =\begin{cases}
\frac{3\log2}{4} & n\ even\\
\ell & n\ odd
\end{cases}$$

where I think $\ell=2\log2-1 $.

Comment: @Babar Your last formula makes no sense as $n$ is a bound variable on the LHS, but a free variable on the RHS (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). The limit in your first comment above makes sense, and I am sure it can be calculated by using the ideas in my post. I have no time to check if it equals $2\log 2-1$, but if you need confirmation, open a new question for it (featuring the limit in your first comment above). Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot. My question about $M=O(n^{1/2})$ was: can we have something like the problem of Dirichlet divisors i.e.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left\{ \frac{F(2n)}{F(k)}\right\} =\frac{3\log2}{2}n+O\left(n^{1/2}\right)$$
I will try to see.

Comment: @Babar I think your last formula holds with a much better error term than $O(n^{1/2})$. The point is that the $k$-sum over each $I(r,n)$ can be determined with great precision, because the terms in it are exponentially close to $0$ or $1$. For example, for $n=10^6$, the sum is $\approx 1039707.22967$, while $\frac{3\log 2}{2}n\approx 1039720.77084$. So for $n=10^6$ the error is about $13.54117$, which is much smaller than $n^{1/2}$.